# How to use a UIView delegate in initialization stage

Tags: ios, uiview, delegates, initialization

I have a view controller which has a couple of views. Those views need data from the model and I use the view controller as a delegate to supply them that data.

The problem is that they need some of that data when they are initialized (in initWithFrame/awakeFromNib). At that stage the delegate is not set yet (it is set in the view controller's viewDidLoad which is called after the view is initialized).

I can solve it by just accessing the model directly from the view, but that will create quite a mess if every view would access models directly.

Where can I set the delegate in order to use it in the view's awakeFromNib/init?

Comment: What kind of data would be needed at the initWithFrame stage, which cannot wait to viewDidLoad or ViewDidAppear?

Comment: Why not set the delegate in awakeFromNib?

Comment: Apparently nothing :) I was caught with the misconception that I had to initialize the views in initWithFrame/awakeFromNib. I'm now calling the initialization methods from viewDidLoad and it works great. Thanks. Sometimes you need someone to state you the obvious :)

Comment: @Rakesh: How could you do that? The delegate is the view controller that has the view. Does a view have access to its view controller?

Comment: @Ata01: But you have a reference to the view from your view controller.  if you have a reference to the view then `self.view.delegate = self` would do it.

Comment: @Rakesh: Yes, this is what I'm currently doing in viewDidLoad. But my problem was that awakeFromNib which is a UIView method is being called before viewDidLoad and in awakeFromNib I don't have any reference to the view controller as far as I know.

Comment: Accessing the controller of a view from the view would be bad practice as view is not supposed to have any knowledge about its controller according to strict MVC. But  `awakeFromNib` is available for the view controller also.